# My textfield is getting cleared automatically

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I am new to iOS development. I am having a weird situation, not every time but very often. My textfield is getting cleared automatically when I come back to the same screen using back button. Code as:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

Problem happens in both simulator and device.

Comment: Can you please add, What code snippet you are trying...?

Comment: sorry for posting this kind of question , actually the problem is when the viewwillappear() is getting called i am clearing all the textfields. Anyhow thanks for your answers and time.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the content view is refreshed everytime when you navigate app to previous `viewController` this make refresh to all ui components as well. What you need to do here just save the `textfields` value temporally to any persistent storage like local db or using `userDefaults` then assign the value again using `viewWillAppear()` method because this method executes everytime when you navigate back your app to vc.

**`viewWillAppear():`** Called just before the view controller’s content view is added to the app’s view hierarchy. Use this method to trigger any operations that need to occur before the content view is presented onscreen. Despite the name, just because the system calls this method, it does not guarantee that the content view will become visible. The view may be obscured by other views or hidden. This method simply indicates that the content view is about to be added to the app’s view hierarchy.

Comment: if we use userdefaults it won't become burden on the app? and the textfields are not getting cleared every time, its happening randomly. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: i know the way that you have mentioned, but i have 50 view controllers. If we create userdefaults in all the 50 view controllers its meaningless. Actually i am searching for some generic way, where we do something and it should reflect throughout the app.

Comment: correct, i'll suggest a another way if i could let me give some time.

Comment: do you know unwind segue? have you used ever passing data to view and get back ?

Comment: are talking about creating a class and storing data into that object?

Comment: no, actually passing data to vc using segue and get the same data back when you navigate back then set. its more preferable way to do.

Comment: ya i know that. i am doing that in few of the screens.

Comment: then you can set data which you have passed and retrieved back ??